# How to translate Groups in a multilingual site?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, multi-sites, group

I have created a new grouptype and added some fields to have a "site". And then created a new group with this grouptype. I edited the overview site with some information. Now I would like to translate the site, because I have an multilingual site. Unfortunately I can't find out how to do so.

Is it possible to translate a groupsite on a multilingual site?
Or do I have to create two groups for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could translate the group node by enable "group" and "group content" in /admin/config/regional/content-language

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be somehow related to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2992499), which is closed and fixed. That issue contains an image which looks like so:

[image]

So check if the version of the Group module that you're using, includes the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-08-17/2992499-2.patch) included in that issue.

If you don't have it included, it's probably why you don't have a "group content type" translation option in `/admin/config/regional/config-translation`. And if you do have it included, go checkout that translation option to see what happens.

Comment: The patch was already included in my version of the grouo modul, but I still can't translate the content of my group node.
I think I should enable the translation for groupe and group content: /admin/config/regional/content-language But when I will enable it, it appears the following error: Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0